# How to change a field value in EF Core Select

Tags: asp.net-core, select, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, ef-core-3.1

Imagine that an entity has many fields and I just want to make changes in 1-2 fields, Is it possible to do that in **Select**? I don't want to mention all fields in my Select cause.

Ex: I want to return all fields and make a tiny change in OrderId field at the same time.

```
_context.Set<Table>.Select(t=>t.OrderId=t.OrderId+1)
```

Comment: You can do it after loading it from database: `var orders = _context.Set<Table>.ToList(); orders.ForEach(item => item.OrderId = item.OrderId + 1)`

Comment: Instead of updating existing, introduce new getter property in the `Table` class which will return "calculated" value.

Comment: 'Is it possible to do that in Select', just in Select without mention all fields can not achieve your expected result. And you can try the workaround that @Fabio mentioned.

Comment: @Fabio I did the same Fabio 

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I've found is to use select and copy every field to a new instance of your entity/object and change the field you want a computed value for, like:

```cs
_context.Operations
   .Where(t => t.SessionId == sessionId)
   .Select(o => new Operation
   {
    OperationId = o.OperationId + 1;
    SessionId = o.SessionId,
    Amount = o.Amount,
    Date = o.Date,
   });
```